# Start-Job scriptblock passing of variable

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, start-job

I got a PowerShell script that starts another script and passes parameters to it. 
I do this with `Start-Job` as I do not want to wait until the second script is finished:

**ScriptA:**

```
start-job -name EnableAutoUnlock -scriptblock {Invoke-Command -script { C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "\\Path\To\Script\EnableAutoUnlock.ps1" $VolumeDriveLetter }}
```

**ScriptB:**

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [string]$drive
)
<do stuff with $drive here>
```

`$VolumeDriveLetter` is just a Drive Letter that gets processed i.e. "C:"

Unfortunately the passing of the Parameter by variable does not work although `$VolumeDriveLetter` has the expected Value but typing it does work correctly.

**Works:**

```
start-job -name EnableAutoUnlock -scriptblock {Invoke-Command -script { C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "\\Path\To\Script\EnableAutoUnlock.ps1" C: }}
```

**Does not Work**

```
$VolumeDriveLetter = "C:"

start-job -name EnableAutoUnlock -scriptblock {Invoke-Command -script { C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "\\Path\To\Script\EnableAutoUnlock.ps1" $VolumeDriveLetter }}
```

EDIT: ScriptB Outputs the passed Variable as empty

What am I missing to get passing of the Variable to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `using` prefix to access the value within a scriptblock:

```
$VolumeDriveLetter = "C:"

start-job -name EnableAutoUnlock -scriptblock {Invoke-Command -script { C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "\\Path\To\Script\EnableAutoUnlock.ps1" $using:VolumeDriveLetter }}
```

Or you use the `-ArgumentList` parameter and pass the parameter to the scriptblock:

```
start-job -name EnableAutoUnlock -scriptblock { 
    Param($VolumeDriveLetter) 
    Write-Host $VolumeDriveLetter 
} -ArgumentList $VolumeDriveLetter
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just tried that and unfortunately it does not work (same as before, the Parameter recieved by scriptB is just empty)

Comment: Thanks alot, i used the edited answer and it worked perfectly